# Error while publishing Bean through JMX

Tags: java, jmx

I am trying to register a bean on JMX. I am getting error on  line `mbs.registerMBean(metadataObj, name);`. Error says

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "(", delete 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token ")", delete 
     this token
```

I have no idea what it is about.

This bean has basic metadata about request start/end time. 
**Class**

```
    package test.performance;

public class RequestPerformanceMetadata implements PerformanceMetadataMBean{

    private double startTime;
    private double endTime;
    private double timeTook;
    private String requestType;
    private int numOfRequests;

    PerformanceMetadataMBean metadataObj = new RequestPerformanceMetadata();

    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName("test.performace:type=PerformanceMetadataMBean");      

    mbs.registerMBean(metadataObj, name);

    public double getTimeTook() {
        return timeTook;
    }
    public void setTimeTook(double timeTook) {
        this.timeTook = timeTook;
    }
```

**Interface**

```
package test.performance;

public interface PerformanceMetadataMBean {

    double getTimeTook();
    void setTimeTook(double timeTook);
    String getRequestType();
    void setRequestType(String requestType);
```

On

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of issues here.

Starting with **msb = ....**, there's no method.... it needs to be in a method.
Next, **new ObjectName(...)** throws an exception, so you need to wrap it in a try/catch block.
Also, are you sure you want to create *another* instance of **RequestPerformanceMetadata** *inside* of **RequestPerformanceMetadata** ? Perhaps you want to simply register the **this** instance.

Take a look at this code fragment:

```
class RequestPerformanceMetadata implements PerformanceMetadataMBean {
    private double startTime;
    private double endTime;
    private double timeTook;
    private String requestType;
    private int numOfRequests;
    private MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    private ObjectName name;

    public RequestPerformanceMetadata() {
        try {
            name = new ObjectName("test.performace:type=PerformanceMetadataMBean"); 
            mbs.registerMBean(this, name);     
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Yo dog. Bad object name", ex);
        }       
    }    
   //........... snip ...........
}
```